# Android Eclipse: Ruined my emulator plus can't detect new Alcatel phone

Tags: android

In the last 36 hours, I've managed to screw my eclipse settings .. from being able to run my app, to now not even launch the emulator properly.

I think it started when I modified the AVD's SD card size and added a camera. Since then I've deleted the AVDs and recreated them. But eclipse now takes 20-30 mins to launch the emulator, and fails while trying to install my apk. When the emulator finally runs, I can't find my app so its not as if its installing and only failing to launch.

Also I bought a new Alcatel Onetouch 918n phone. After some painful steps, I now see "Alcatel Android ADB interface" in Device manager. But I just can't seem to make this phone visible to Eclipse/ddms/adb.

I don't have many logs to paste here- not sure what I should include. HELP!!!!

Comment: fyi, this is the msg when launching the app on emulator

[2012-10-20 23:24:51 - myappname] Installing myappname.apk...
[2012-10-20 23:26:59 - myappname] Failed to install myappname.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-10-20 23:26:59 - myappname] (null)
[2012-10-20 23:27:00 - myappname] Launch canceled!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just creating a new virtual machine?  A lot of times changing sd card values ect can make it take much longer to load as well, you can also export to the .apk and load it onto your phone manually to test (tedious).

Comment: hi you're right.. i did try this several times however - deleting/recreating AVDs. the latest update (last 5 mins!) is that a latest avd i created, seems to take only 5 mins to launch, and while eclipse says it can't install the apk, it seems to be doing it.